# ggplot legend.box.background produces strange relics

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a bit harder to explain than [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70833835/ggplot-multiple-legends-into-one-box) because the problem is not *exactly* reproducible.

I am producing legends for a couple of maps and am drawing a box around both legends since one has only 1 item (a line feature) and the others are discrete fills (a polygon feature). Using geom_sf to plot both.

I end up with a weird artefact that looks like part of the lines are drawn twice with just a slightly shifted position.

[image: notice the bottom right corner!!!]

I managed to produce a similar error with the iris dataset where legend.box.background is only partially drawn.

```
data(iris)

ggplot(iris)+theme_classic()+
  geom_point(aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Sepal.Length, color=Species, size=Sepal.Width))+
  scale_color_manual(name=NULL, values=c("red","green","blue") ,labels=c("supersupersupersuperlong", "test2", "test3"))+
  theme(legend.position=c(0.1,0.75),legend.box.background=element_rect(fill="white", color="black"), legend.spacing.y=unit(0,"cm"))
```

**UPDATE**

I noticed in my original example it had to do with text length, so I tried adding a space after some of the labels which changes the "arrangement" of the twice-drawn lines a little bit. But I can't find an arrangement of whitespace that makes it go away completely.
Anyone know how to manually change the size of the legend.box.background. If not I will draw a geometric rectangle and call it quits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem here is that the `legend.background` (which is a white rectangle behind *each component* of your legend), is partially drawing over the line surrounding the `legend.box`, which is the rectangle surrounding the *whole* legend. You can simply remove the `legend.background`

For example, your plot goes from this:

```r
ggplot(iris) + 
  theme_classic() +
  geom_point(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Sepal.Length, color = Species, 
                 size = Sepal.Width)) +
  scale_color_manual(name = NULL, values = c("red", "green", "blue"),
                     labels = c("supersupersupersuperlong", "test2", "test3")) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.1, 0.75),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "black"), 
        legend.spacing.y = unit(0, "cm"))
```

[image]

To this:

```r
ggplot(iris) + 
  theme_classic() +
  geom_point(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Sepal.Length, color = Species, 
                 size = Sepal.Width)) +
  scale_color_manual(name = NULL, values = c("red", "green", "blue"),
                     labels = c("supersupersupersuperlong", "test2", "test3")) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.1, 0.75),
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "black"), 
        legend.spacing.y = unit(0, "cm"))
```

[image]